# Error al agregar controller con vistas

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mvc, entity-framework

Estoy usando Entity Framework MVC C# y tengo un problema al agregar un controlador con vistas en cualquier proyecto de MVC (me sale el error de la imagen y al dar aceptar vuelve a la ventana de creación del controller):

[image: Mensaje de error]

Les comento que comenzó a hacer esto luego de que yo eliminara un controlador en un proyecto y todas sus vistas correspondientes. Como era un proyecto que recién comenzaba opté por eliminarlo y comenzar uno nuevo, pero ahora el error me aparece en cada controller que quiero crear en cualquier proyecto que realizo. ¿Qué podrá ser?

Comment: Podrias compartir el código del modelo `Usuario`.

Comment: El codigo no es el problema, ya que haga la clase que haga, haga el proyecto que haga, cuando quiero hacer el controller obtengo el mismo mensaje, sólo que cambia el nombre de la clase y el proyecto(en este caso usuario)

Comment: No has considerado reinstalar en EntityFramework? En Nuget podrias tratar de desinstalarlo e instalarlo de nuevo.

Comment: que tal amigo te cuento que hice, primero cierra y respaldar el proyecto, segundo abrir en el explorador la raíz de tu proyecto vas a encontrar una carpeta que se llama  llama".vs", debes eliminarla, vuelve a compilar todo el proyecto; en caso de que no funciona repite a operación y ahora buscar también dentro de tu proyecto la carpeta bin y eliminala, vuelve a compilar, eso me funciono

Comment: @allexiusw, eso ya lo habia hecho y no funciono

Comment: @HoracioXochitemol eso si funciono, muy agradecido amigo, no se como marcar que tu respuesta es la solucion al problema, asi que si alguien puede editar tu comentario como solucion, les agradezco

Comment: Espera a que @HoracioXochitemol lo haga, ya que el tiene el credito de la respuesta correcta.

Comment: Como lo mencionó @Horacio Xochitemol primero debes cerar y respaldar el proyecto en el que estas trabajando, luego abrir en el explorador la raíz `/` de tu proyecto encontraras una carpeta que se llama llama `.vs`, debes eliminarla, luego vuelve compilar todo el proyecto; en caso de que no funciona repite la operación y busca también dentro de tu proyecto la carpeta `bin` y eliminala, vuelve a compilar y eso debe `No se pueden recuperar metadatos para tu modelo`.

Comment: He dejado la respuesta de @Horacio Xochitemol, marcala como correcta, yo no ganaré puntos por ello, ya que esta como wiki de la comunidad, mi objetivo es que cuando alguien tenga el mismo problema, de forma fácil pueda encontrar la ayuda.